# Passport local is saving 3 documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am having an issue with a single request (can see logs confirming it) to my Node.js application that uses Express.js and Passport.js's local strategy where when I sign up a new user it will save 3 documents inside the mongo DB and then when I try to do anything after that the indexes are so messed up that any request I make says a duplicate key error.

Below is my route code as well as my user model. I suspect the issue lies in one of them as the only other code that should be running is my DB connection and my main express configuration.

Route code

```
// Routes
router.post( "/signup",
    passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        const newUser = new User({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password});
        User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err){ // Can add 'user' after 'err'
            if(err){
                logger.error(err.message);
                let errorMessage = null;
                if(err.message == "A user with the given username is already registered") {
                    errorMessage = "A user with that email is already registered";
                } else {
                    errorMessage = err.message;
                }
                return res.status(400).json({success: false, message: errorMessage});
            }
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                return res.json({success: true});
            });
        });
    }
);
```

User model

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        // index: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        match: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

// Indexes for better performance, especially for queries involving username or email

UserSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
    try {
        // check method of registration
        const user = this;
        if (!user.isModified("password")) next();
        // generate salt
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        // hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
        // replace plain text password with hashed password
        this.password = hashedPassword;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
    try {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};


UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: "email"});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```